# Update query return false in Android

Tags: android

I want to update specific row value in Sq-lite db table when i click on Auto-complete list-view. Here is my db helper code .

```
 public boolean updateFilterUser(String strUserName)
  {
      SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(COL_AllPost_ActivityStatus, "1");
      values.put(COL_AllPost_inspectorname, strUserName);
      int i = db.update(Table_AllPost_Table, values, COL_AllPost_inspectorname + "= ? ", new String[]{strUserName});

      return i > 0;
  }
```

And here is the Activity code

```
  userAutoComplete_TextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoComplete_UserList);
        userAutoComplete_TextView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userlist));
        userAutoComplete_TextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                String foundItem = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
                boolean inputQuery = dbhelper.updateFilterUser(foundItem);
                Log.e("Post ", " Edited Succesfully !!!" + inputQuery);

                Filter filter = new Filter();
                filter.setName(foundItem);
                filter_ArrayList.add(filter);
                filterAdapter = new FilterAdapter(Filter_Screen.this, R.layout.filter_list_item, filter_ArrayList);
                listView_Filter.setAdapter(filterAdapter);

                Log.e("Updated ListView --->", "" + foundItem);

            }
        });
```

My row is not update .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lie this I hope this will help you.

```
public boolean updateFilterUser(String strUserName){

  SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put(COL_AllPost_ActivityStatus, "1");

  String selection = COL_AllPost_inspectorname + " LIKE ?";
  String[] selectionArgs = {strUserName};
  int i = db.update(Table_AllPost_Table, values, selection, selectionArgs);

  return true;
}
```

Comment: even getting return false

Comment: Actually i update row this way =  db.execSQL("update ALL_Post set ActiveStatus='1' where inspectorName=='" + foundItem + "'"); but  update fail . So thats why i getting this code ( updateFilterUser() ) from net.

Comment: I want to change the COL_AllPost_ActivityStatus  0 to 1 where name XXXXXXXX

Comment: you have to return only `true` only nothing else

Comment: See i edit my answer. do like that may be its will help

Comment: Getting error  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Admin": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE ALL_Post SET ActiveStatus=? WHERE inspectorName=JiBe Admin  and here is method   public boolean updateFilterUser(String strUserName){

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_AllPost_ActivityStatus, "1");
        int i = db.update(Table_AllPost_Table, values, COL_AllPost_inspectorname + "=" + strUserName, null);

        return i > 0;
    }